# Artifacts appear using imread function from opencv

Tags: matlab, opencv, jpeg, libjpeg

I use imread function to read one jpeg file and save the rgb image in bmp format. Comparing the two files, I found artifacts appear and use green circle to denote artifacts. The version of OpenCV is 3.0. I compile the libraries by myself with SSE, SSE2 and SSE3 switchd on (default setting). My OS is windows 7 professional. You can use the following image to check.

[original jpeg image](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1mgnKE3e)

[saved bmp file](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1gd6RGTP)

If I read the jpeg file in Matlab, the rgb image is correct. I save rgb image in png format in Matlab, read the png file using opencv and save the loaded image in bmp file. Everything is OK. It seems that there is a problem with jpeg decoder. The jpeg library used is libjpeg.lib.

Due to the size limit, I cut the patch from the second image.
[image]

Comment: I dont see differences between both images on my mobile phone. can you explain how the artifacts look like and where they are visible?

Comment: In the second image, there is a green circle where several horizontal pink lines appear. In the original image, such lines don't exist.

Comment: sorry, no green circle or pink horizontal lines visible for me in the 2nd image. Are you certain you uploaded the right file?!?

Comment: From my computer, I can see the green circle from the link of the second image. I cut the patch which contains the artifact and paste the patch in the post.

Comment: ok... it IS visible in the second image but too small for my mobile phone display.

Answer (score 0):

You're always going to get some artifacts in JPEG. You can reduce the appearance of such artifacts by changing the quantization tables used (usually with loss of compression).

JPEG encoders often use a "quality" setting to change the quantization tables.

Comment: I agree with you on the artifact that jpeg encoder may produce. However, the artifacts appear while I am using imread function. It means that the artifacts are generated by jpeg decoder rather than jpeg encoder.

Comment: Only JPEG image need to be decoded which is lossy compression in essence. BMP image only encapsulates image data in the bmp file.

Comment: BMP uses RLE compression.